WebSocket Protocol (RFC 6455) Fragmented message has no FIN bit and headers
I'm trying to parse websocket framed message with RFC6455 and I noticed that only the first frame has a header, and the subsequent ones do not
I solved this problem using payload_length, but it doesn't work with binary messages.
I am sending a 5mb message and receiving all 5mb via tcp socket, but payload_length = 131000
Idk what to do...
How to determine is message full arrived to server
import socket
import hashlib
import base64
import struct

import signal
import sys

Frame_Mode = False

Full_Package_Size = 0
Got_Data = 0

Full_Package = b""

def generate_websocket_key(key):
    GUID = "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11"
    hash_value = hashlib.sha1(key.encode() + GUID.encode()).digest()
    return base64.b64encode(hash_value).decode()

def Parse():
    #opcode = Full_Package[0] & 0x0F
    masked = (Full_Package[1] & 0x80) >> 7
    payload_length = Full_Package[1] & 0x7F

    if payload_length == 126:
        payload_length = struct.unpack('!H', Full_Package[2:4])[0]
        offset = 4
    elif payload_length == 127:
        payload_length = struct.unpack('!Q', Full_Package[2:10])[0]
        offset = 10
    else:
        offset = 2

    #print(payload_length)

    if masked:
        masking_key = Full_Package[offset:offset+4]
        offset += 4
        payload = bytearray()
        for i in range(payload_length):
            payload.append(Full_Package[offset + i] ^ masking_key[i % 4])
    else:
        payload = Full_Package[offset:offset+payload_length]

    print(len(payload))


def parse_websocket_frame(data):
    global Frame_Mode, Full_Package_Size, Got_Data, Full_Package, PC

    u_data = data[:2]
    #print(u_data)
    head1, head2 = struct.unpack("BB", u_data) #bytearray(b'\xc1\xab')
    fin = (data[0] & 0b10000000)

    opcode_byte = (data[0] & 0b00001111).to_bytes(1, byteorder='big')

    Got_Data += len(data)
    print(f"fin: {fin} opcode: {opcode_byte} len: {Got_Data}")
    #print(u_data)

    payload_length = data[1] & 0x7F

    masked = (data[1] & 0x80) >> 7

    if payload_length == 126:
        payload_length = struct.unpack('!H', data[2:4])[0]
        offset = 4
    elif payload_length == 127:
        payload_length = struct.unpack('!Q', data[2:10])[0]
        offset = 10
    else:
        offset = 2

    if masked:
        offset += 4


def handle_client(client_socket):
    request = client_socket.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
    print("Received request:\n", request)

    headers = request.split('\r\n')
    websocket_key = ""
    for header in headers:
        if header.startswith("Sec-WebSocket-Key:"):
            websocket_key = header.split(":")[1].strip()

    if websocket_key:
        accept_key = generate_websocket_key(websocket_key)
        response = (
            "HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols\r\n"
            "Upgrade: websocket\r\n"
            "Connection: Upgrade\r\n"
            f"Sec-WebSocket-Accept: {accept_key}\r\n"
            "\r\n"
        )
        client_socket.send(response.encode('utf-8'))
        print("Handshake completed")

        while True:
            data = client_socket.recv(1024)
            #print(len(data))
            #print("\n")
            if not data:
                print("Empty Package")
                #break
            message = parse_websocket_frame(data)
            #print(f"Received message: {message}")
            #print("\n")

    client_socket.close()

def signal_handler(sig, frame, server_socket):
    print('Program terminated by user')
    server_socket.close()
    sys.exit(0)

def main():

    server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    server_socket.bind(('localhost', 56000))
    server_socket.listen(5)
    print("Server listening on port 56000")

    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, lambda sig, frame: signal_handler(sig, frame, server_socket))

    while True:
        client_socket, addr = server_socket.accept()
        print(f"Accepted connection from {addr}")
        handle_client(client_socket)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

I tried to reverse code of Websockets library, but it's too complicated for me, I'm a C++ developer. Use Python only for debug properties.
